# Embed PDF Stream from API with Wordpress, Ajax and Curl

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, php-curl

I had an HTML embed tag with as src a direct call to an API that returns a PDF stream, it worked very well.
This API needs to be secure, I can no longer make direct calls to the API. So I go through Ajax (via wordpress) to update the calls to this API through php curl in my php functions. It works very well with calls to the API in post with classic data, however I have a problem displaying this PDF, I don't know how to do it.
Here are my different tries that didn't work:

```
// PHP
function action_php_pdf(){
  $api_url = esc_url("https://www.apiurl.com/Get/pdf?param=paramval";
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $api_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  ));
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  $pdf_base64 = base64_encode($response);
  echo '<embed class="convention-embed" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' . $pdf_base64 . '" width=800 height=500 type="application/pdf"/>';
  die();
}

// JS
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action : 'action_php_pdf'
  }
}).done(function(data) {
      $('.embed-parent').html(data);
});
```

Does not work because curl_exec outputs the result of the stream, so we get the raw pdf stream + an embed in error

```
// PHP
function action_php_pdf(){
  $api_url = esc_url("https://www.apiurl.com/Get/pdf?param=paramval";
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $api_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  ));
  curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  die();
}


// JS
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action : 'action_php_pdf'
  }
}).done(function(data) {
      var blob = new Blob( [data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      var url = (window.URL ? URL : webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
      $('.class-on-embed').attr('src', url);
});
```

Doesn't work: the embed looks like a pdf with several pages, but the pages are blank and the blob url redirects to a 404...

Do you have any suggestions to achieve this please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to avoid the problem by using php ob_start...etc functions to prevent the output, I put it here if that can help anyone who see this post:

```
// PHP
function action_php_pdf(){
  $api_url = esc_url("https://www.apiurl.com/Get/pdf?param=paramval";
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL            => $api_url,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
  ));
  ob_start();
  curl_exec($curl);
  $response = ob_get_contents();
  curl_close($curl);
  ob_end_clean();
  $pdf_base64 = base64_encode($response);
  echo '<embed class="convention-embed" src="data:application/pdf;base64,' . $pdf_base64 . '" width=800 height=500 type="application/pdf"/>';
  die();
}

// JS
$.ajax({
  url: ajaxurl,
  type: "POST",
  data: {
    action : 'action_php_pdf'
  }
}).done(function(data) {
      $('.embed-parent').html(data);
});
```